# Почему не стартует JavaFx , вроде все подключил

Tags: javafx

```
Ничего не трогал , даже стартовый шаблон не запускает     


"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2\bin\java.exe" --add-modules javafx.base,javafx.graphics --add-reads javafx.base=ALL-UNNAMED --add-reads javafx.graphics=ALL-UNNAMED "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=60195:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Users\shevc\IdeaProjects\MyApp\out\production\MyApp;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2\lib\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx-swt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2\lib\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.base.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2\lib\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.controls.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2\lib\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.fxml.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2\lib\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.graphics.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2\lib\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.media.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2\lib\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.swing.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2\lib\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.web.jar" -p "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2\lib\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.base.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2\lib\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.graphics.jar" sample.Main
    Exception in Application start method
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper (in unnamed module @0x29b5b976) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.util.Utils (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.util to unnamed module @0x29b5b976
        at com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper.<clinit>(FXMLLoaderHelper.java:38)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.<clinit>(FXMLLoader.java:2056)
        at sample.Main.start(Main.java:13)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
        ... 1 more
    Exception running application sample.Main

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил сам
Run --> Edit Configuration --> VM option --> Прописал 
--module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib" 
--add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml

Может кому поможет..